# Get the last selected option in RadioGroup Extjs4

Tags: extjs4, radio-group

IS there any way to get the last selected option in the radio group?

Comment: I have gone through this link http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.RadioGroup , but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually add listener on change:

```
      radGrp = {xtype: 'radiogroup',
...
  previousVal:undefined,
  listeners:[
    change: function( this, newValue, oldValue, eOpts )
  {this.previousVal = oldValue;}
  ]}
```

After this you can access to this attribute

```
      var getRadPrevious= function(){
        return radGrp.previousVal;
  }
```

Comment: Is there any function is available to get this?